# ffmpeg video speed change non functioning from with python

Tags: python, performance, ffmpeg

So I am trying to change the speed of the video to twice its speed using ffmpeg

```
                          cmd="ffmpeg -i C:\\Users\\Samhita\\Desktop\\EDOS\\D4.mp4 -filter_complex \"[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a]\" -map \"[v]\" -map \"[a]\" 2.mp4"
                          subprocess_call(cmd.split))
```

It work fine when i run it from winthin the command line and has problem when i run it within the python module 
 The error is as follows:

```
        C:\moviepy-master>python speed_change.py
        ffmpeg version 2.8.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
          built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
          configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
        isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
        le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
        enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
        ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
        le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --en
        able-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --ena
        ble-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
         --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enabl
        e-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --ena
        ble-decklink --enable-zlib
          libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
          libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
          libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
          libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
          libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
          libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
          libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
          libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
        Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\moviepy-master\part3.mp4':
          Metadata:
            major_brand     : isom
            minor_version   : 512
            compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
            encoder         : Lavf57.75.100
          Duration: 00:07:24.01, start: 0.006009, bitrate: 772 kb/s
            Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yu
        v420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 640x360, 639 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1
        1988 tbn, 23976 tbc (default)
            Metadata:
              handler_name    : VideoHandler
            Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp,
         126 kb/s (default)
            Metadata:
              handler_name    : SoundHandler
        [AVFilterGraph @ 046560a0] No such filter: '"'
        Error initializing complex filters.
        Invalid argument
```